# Show Activity bar in android

Tags: android

I have to implement activity bar which describes here in,in my project.

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html

If anyone know how to do this please help me.I have searched a lot for a way to do this.

Comment: use progressbar with your actionbar or actionbarsherlock if use version less than 11...

Comment: I am trying to implement that.thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use Action Bar Sherlock (less than api 3). For more Please click [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) . thank you :)

Comment: Where has the OP mentioned he is on api < 3?

Comment: I am using appcompat libraries.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private boolean useLogo = false;
private boolean showHomeUp = true;

ActionMode mMode;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mProgressRunner = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mProgress += 2;

        //Normalize our progress along the progress bar's scale
        int progress = (Window.PROGRESS_END - Window.PROGRESS_START) / 100 * mProgress;
        setSupportProgress(progress);

        if (mProgress < 100) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mProgressRunner, 50);
        }
    }
};

private int mProgress = 100;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

    // set defaults for logo & home up
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showHomeUp);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(useLogo);


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.progress)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mProgress == 100) {
                mProgress = 0;
                mProgressRunner.run();
            }
        }
    });   
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    // set up a listener for the refresh item
    final MenuItem refresh = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh);
    refresh.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        // on selecting show progress spinner for 1s
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // item.setActionView(R.layout.progress_action);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    refresh.setActionView(null);
                }
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // TODO handle clicking the app icon/logo
        return false;
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        // switch to a progress animation
        item.setActionView(R.layout.indeterminate_progress_action);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Progress" />
</LinearLayout>
```

indeterminate_progress_action.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ProgressBar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:indeterminate="true"
 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/progress_action_padding"
 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/progress_action_padding" />
```

menu/main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_refresh" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_label_refresh" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh_holo_dark" />
 </menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.actionbarstyleexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.MainActivity" 
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ad_logo"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```